# Add optional segment to Craft Commerce product Url

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, routes

I currently have a Craft Commerce site where the product url is setup like this:

`{productCategory.level(1).first().slug}/{productCategory.level(2).first().slug}/{productCategory.level(3).first().slug}/{slug}`

So this gives an example url of `category1/category2/category3/my-product`

This all works fine. What I'd like to do is add an optional segment onto the end of this url, so for example:

`category1/category2/category3/my-product/optional-thing`.

I'd like the current urls to continue working, but if you add the extra `optional-thing` segment to the url you also get the same product.

Ultimately this is so that I can preselect a variant in a carousel on the product detail page.

I've tried doing this with routes, but so far I've been unsuccessful. Is this the right approach or is there a better, more Commerce specific way?